Help with Inverse Laplace using Convolution
Im trying to solve this inverse Laplace transform using a convolution integral with integration by parts (DI Method) but I think its not working or at least I can't see any error.
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{\frac{2s}{(s^2+1)^2}\right\} $$
This is what I did:
$$ 2\cdot \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{\frac{s}{s^2+1}\cdot \frac{1}{s^2+1} \right\} = \cos t \ast \sin t $$
$$ \cos t \ast \sin t = \int_0^t \cos(t-u) \sin(u) \, \mathrm{d}u = I$$

DI Method:
\begin{array}{c|c}
\ \text{} & \text{D} & \text{I} \\
\hline
\text{+} & \text{$\cos(t-u)$} & \text{$\sin(u)$} \\
\text{-} & \text{$\sin(t-u)$} & \text{$-\cos(u)$} \\
\text{+} & \text{$-\cos(t-u)$} & \text{$-\sin(u)$} \\
\end{array}
So I end with:
$$ I = -\cos(t-u)\cos(u) + \sin(t-u)\sin(u) + I $$
$$ I-I = -\cos(t-u)\cos(u) + \sin(t-u)\sin(u) $$
I can't solve for $I$. What did I do wrong?

Here's an alternate method to the convolution and generalized,
Consider the standard formula,
$$\mathcal{L}\{\sin{(at)}\}=\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$$
Using the derivative property,
$$\color{red}{\mathcal{L}\{t^nx(t)\}=(-1)^n\frac{\mathrm{d^n}}{\mathrm{d}s^n}x(s)}$$
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{t\sin{(at)}\}
&=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\mathcal{L}\{\sin{(at)}\}\\
&=\frac{2as}{(s^2+a^2)^2}\\
\end{align}$$
Now set $a=1$,
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{2s}{(s^2+1)^2}\right\}=t\sin{(t)}$$

An alternative angle of approach: use the formula
$$
\sin a \cos b = \frac{\sin(a+b) + \sin(a-b)}{2}
$$
